# Google Maps geocoder.geocode Limit

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm placing up to 25 markers on a map but when I hit 12 I get an error of "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT".

I have hit nowhere near the 2,500 hits a day limit.

If I try and plot only 11 markers I have no problem.

Any one know why this is?

**edit**

Ok, a lot of testing and I have determined that I can't call `geocoder.geocode` more than a certain number of times before I have to wait until the calls are done.

I have implemented a version that sends a bunch of requests, waits and then sends more and it's working but it's a total fudge.

Is there a way to geocode a bunch of addresses at once without this limitation?

My client does not store the latlng of the addresses so I need to get that from the address.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Maybe a link that demonstrates the problem, a sample of the code that shows how you create the markers, etc.

Comment: Sorry, not at this point.  Site is not live and there is a lot of code for the markers.

Comment: How are you figuring out the latitude / longitude for the markers?

Comment: Please see my edit for more information thanks

Answer (score 1):

The JS geocoder is rate limited:

"The Google Maps API provides a geocoder class for geocoding addresses dynamically from user input. These requests are rate-limited to discourage abuse of the service. If instead, you wish to geocode static, known addresses, see the Geocoding web service documentation."

From http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding.html#Geocoding

The web service documentation also mentions a rate limit, but presumably it's higher:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits

Answer (score 0):

You can also cache addresses for a limited amount of time for performance purposes. That would allow you to check your cache first before running into the problem.